# Batch файл уходит в цикл при команде SORT

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Всем привет!

Есть код, который ищет заданную строку в одном файле, потом сортирует то что нашел и пихает в другой.

На моей винде при запуске батник уходит в цикл.

Код:

```
@echo off
Set /P filename=file name: %filename%
Set /P request=request: %request%
FIND /I "%request%" %filename% | SORT > sort.txt
```

Записал [гифку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45KZB.jpg) как работает батник.

Проблема наблюдается именно на моем хосте, на компьютере друга все отлично.

Comment: Вам не кажется, что вызывать батник из самого себя - это и есть бесконечный цикл? Имя батника **sort.bat** совпадает с именем вызываемой утилиты **sort.exe**

Answer (score 0):

> Вам не кажется, что вызывать батник из самого себя - это и есть бесконечный цикл? Имя батника sort.bat совпадает с именем вызываемой утилиты sort.exe

Спасибо, Daemon5!